# Run linux Script from Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, exec

I have the following java code

```
ArrayList<String> argList = new ArrayList<>();
argList.add("Hello");
argList.add("World");
String[] args = argList.toArray(new String[argList.size()]);

Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo '$1 $2' ", args);
```

result is `$1 $2` but i want to print `Hello World`.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is it your real code because in this example you are executing `args` not `argList`.

Comment: @ user2699859 : The single quotes escapes the $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a shell to use the parameter expansion:

```
ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
command.add("bash");
command.add("-c");
command.add("echo \"$0\" \"$1\"");
command.addAll(argList);

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toArray(new String[1]));
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `exec(String[] args)` method, instead:

```java
    String[] cmdArgs = { "echo", "Hello", "World!" };
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArgs);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

The problem is, that the first argument in the `exec()` method is not the script, but the name of the script.

If you want to use variables, like `$1` and `$2` you should do that in your script.

So, what you actually might want is:

```java
    String[] cmdArgs = { "myscript", "Hello", "World!" };
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> argList = new ArrayList<>();
argList.add("echo");
argList.add("Hello");
argList.add("World");

Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
```

This way the `String[]` will be passed as an argument to `echo`.

If you want to use `$` then you will have to write a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Echo will print all arguments as such. In your case '$1 $2' is interpreted as normal string.. Since it will anyway print all args you could  use some thing like below.

```
  ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder().command("/bin/echo.exe", "hello", "world\n");
```

Another option is co create a small script  say `mycommands.sh`  with appropriate contents

```
   echo $@ 
   echo $1 $2  
   #any such
```

You then invoke your script... like

```
  ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder().command("/bin/bash" , "-c", "<path to script > ", "hello", "world\n");
```

Note the use of ProcessBuilder.  This is an improved api instead of Runtime.(especially for quoting etc)